# Use ffmpeg for JPEG to TIFF conversion

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg, tiff, image-conversion, tesseract-ocr

I would like to use [Tesseract OCR](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) with a video.

With ffmpeg I can export some (`.jpeg`) images from a video. Can I convert a `.jpeg` into a valid `.tiff` or export directly `.tiff` images from the video with ffmpeg?

Comment: I think you can export directly to tiff from ffmpeg... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717331/convert-video-file-to-tiff-with-ffmpeg-dll-or-avcodec-dll-is-on-the-fly-possi

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply! No, the links in that accepted answer are broken and the other answers didn't export correcly `.tiff` images.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Converting to TIFF**

You can convert a JPEG to TIFF:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpeg -pix_fmt rgba output.tiff
```

Or from a video:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -pix_fmt rgba out%05d.tiff
```

What's important is specifying the RGBA colorspace via `-pix_fmt rgba`. Keeping the YUV 4:2:0 colorspace from video (`-pix_fmt yuv420p`) would produce TIFF files that cannot be opened in most programs (even though the YCbCr<sup>*</sup> colorspace is allowed).

**How to compress output**

By default this produces uncompressed TIFF images. You can choose a different compression algorithm using the `-compression_algo` option:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpeg -pix_fmt rgb24 -compression_algo lzw output.tiff
```

Valid options are `packbits`, `raw`, `lzw` and `deflate` (see `ffmpeg -h encoder=tiff`).

<sub>* YCbCr refers to what in video compression is usually known as YUV</sub>

Comment: Wow, amazing! That solve my problem! :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Using this method, I end up with TIFFs that are huge compared to outputting (say) PNG and then converting to TIFF using ImageMagick; something that 0.5MB vs 3MB. Do you know why that is? Presumably something to do with compression. How do I enable lossless compression on the TIFFs?\

Comment: @Ray See updated answer, there are some options for specifying compression algorithms.

Comment: what is  ```-pix_fmt```? can you please tell what command I need to run inorder to compress the image without change the file extension?

Comment: @MaheshJamdade It's the color space/color format of the input. If you simply want to compress an image without changing extension, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261855/recommendation-for-compressing-jpg-files-with-imagemagick or similar.

Comment: @slhck thanks for the response but I am looking for a ffmpeg solution because I am using this https://github.com/tanersener/flutter-ffmpeg