# Convert from avi to uncompressed tiff using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, tiff

In [Use ffmpeg for JPEG to TIFF conversion](https://superuser.com/questions/827606/use-ffmpeg-for-jpeg-to-tiff-conversion)
there is an answer how to convert to TIFF.

So, I followed that process written on that answer:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -pix_fmt rgb24 output.tiff
```

Though the TIFF file converted then became lossless compressed TIFF files.

How can I convert it to uncompressed TIFF files?

Comment: As LordNeckbeard edited, there is a way to do it. However, I followed that, and it was converted to compressed TIFF files. I needed uncompressed files, so unfortunately, it didn't help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Example

The option you need is `-compression_algo` with a value of `raw` or `1`:

```
ffmpeg -i input -compression_algo raw -pix_fmt rgb24 output.tiff
```

As for the reason for the `-pix_fmt rgb24` option see answer to [Use `ffmpeg` for JPEG to TIFF conversion](https://superuser.com/a/827897/110524).

## Private options

You can view information and options specific to each encoder (also called "private options"):

```
$ ffmpeg -v error -h encoder=tiff
Encoder tiff [TIFF image]:
    Threading capabilities: frame
    Supported pixel formats: rgb24 pal8 gray ya8 gray16le monob monow yuv420p yuv422p yuv440p yuv444p yuv410p yuv411p rgb48le rgba rgba64le
TIFF encoder AVOptions:
  -dpi               <int>        E..V.... set the image resolution (in dpi) (from 1 to 65536) (default 72)
  -compression_algo  <int>        E..V.... (from 1 to 32946) (default 32773)
     packbits                     E..V....
     raw                          E..V....
     lzw                          E..V....
     deflate                      E..V....
```