# How can I convert a multipage tiff to a lossless movie on the command line?

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, tiff

`ffmpeg` can convert sequences of [images](https://superuser.com/questions/827606/use-ffmpeg-for-jpeg-to-tiff-conversion) to movies and is capable of producing [lossless](https://superuser.com/questions/347433/how-to-create-an-uncompressed-avi-from-a-series-of-1000s-of-png-images-using-ff) output. Is it possible to directly produce a movie from a multi-page tiff file? If I try one of my multipage tiffs ffmpeg only processes the first frame.

Comment: FFmpeg doesn't support reading TIFF pages. You can use Imagemagick to split the TIFF pages to an image sequence first.

Comment: That would be very slow for large TIFF stacks and double the memory required for the stack.Ideally I would like something that can also handle BigTIFF files (extension of TIFF over 4GB limit).

Answer (score 3):

### Workaround

FFmpeg does not support multipage tiff yet, even in 2021! In the actual FFmpeg feature ticket, I found a workaround: use `convert` (from ImageMagick) to pipe individual images to FFmpeg. 
Ref: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8644

In my case, the file format is gray16le (16bits grayscale LE, from a thermal IR camera):

```
convert sample.tif gray:- | ffmpeg -f rawvideo -s 1280x1024 -pix_fmt gray16le -r 30 -i - -vcodec ffv1 sample-ffv1.mkv
```

The `ffv1` is a lossless format, but it is still compressed. In my case it was about 30% of the original size.

I used the `-r 30` to set the output framerate.

### Note

Some may wonder why we need lossless 16bit format: I needed to simulate a 16bit grayscale V4L source using V4L-loopback:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i sample-ffv1.mkv -map 0:v -f v4l2 /dev/video0
```